# Unable to locate element in textarea in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver

I have a html block for text area like this:

```
<div id="block-517e9e97-d25b-41b1-8108-463e0137df8c" class="wp-block block-editor-block-list__block has-selected-ui" data-block="517e9e97-d25b-41b1-8108-463e0137df8c" data-type="core/paragraph" tabindex="0" aria-label="Block: Paragraph" role="group" style="" xpath="1">
    <p role="textbox" aria-multiline="true" aria-label="Empty block; start writing or type forward slash to choose a block" style="" class="rich-text block-editor-rich-text__editable wp-block-paragraph" contenteditable="true">
        <span data-rich-text-placeholder="Start writing or type / to choose a block" contenteditable="false">
        </span>
    </p>
</div>

<p role="textbox" aria-multiline="true" aria-label="Empty block; start writing or type forward slash to choose a block" style="" class="rich-text block-editor-rich-text__editable wp-block-paragraph" xpath="1" contenteditable="true">
    <span data-rich-text-placeholder="Start writing or type / to choose a block" contenteditable="false">
    </span>
</p>
```

I trying to locate element by using id, xpath, css selector but they aren't working. I don't see name or tagname so what should I do to resolve this problem?

Java code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="block-517e9e97-d25b-41b1-8108-463e0137df8c"]")).sendKeys("This is text area");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because in the xpath you have used "" twice and thus exited the string:

> Instead of: `"//*[@id="block-517e9e97-d25b-41b1-8108-463e0137df8c"]"`
>
> Try using: `"//*[@id='block-517e9e97-d25b-41b1-8108-463e0137df8c']"`

Use " for the xpath and ' for the id name

Answer (score 0):

driver.findElement(By.id("block-517e9e97-d25b-41b1-8108-463e0137df8c")).sendKeys("text");

when you inspect web elements if you have identify elements by id first use that id and perform action because id is unique, if you don't have id then only go to Xpath